# Why is a boolean expression valid in a case block, when booleans are not supported data types for switches?

Tags: java, switch-statement, scjp, java-6, ocpjp

After reading some of the SCJP certification last night, I got thinking about switch statements and how the expressions are evaluated, and I'm a little puzzled by something.

Java won't let you switch on a boolean, so the following will not compile :

```
public static void switchOnBoolean(boolean theBool)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\nAssessing boolean :" + theBool);
        // line below won't compile, since booleans are not valid for the switch statement
        switch(theBool)
        {
            case true:
            {
                System.out.println("The boolean was true");
                break;
            }
            case false:
            {
                System.out.println("The boolean was false");
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the compiler will not complain if you attempt to use an expression that evaluates to a boolean value in a case block, such as :

```
public static void switchOnChar(char theChar)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\nAssessing char : " + theChar);
        switch(theChar)
        {
            case 'a':
            {
                System.out.println("The char was a");
                break;
            }
            case 'b':
            {
                System.out.println("The char was b");
                break;
            }
            case ('c' | 'd'):
            {
                System.out.println("The char was c or d");
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("The char didn't match anything, must be something else");
            }
        }
    }
```

Ultimately, I can't ever get into the case `('c' | 'd')` since it would presumably evaluate to a boolean...

**So my question is:**

1. Why is it legal to use something like `('c' | 'd')` ?
2. How could that ever be useful, since that would be unreachable
3. If you ever wanted to case on more than one value, but without using a default, is your only choice to re-implement as an if-else statement?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1

Comment: The compared values are not booleans, so this is not going to be a boolean comparison, but instead a bitwise operation. System.out.println('c' | 'd'); // will output 103

Comment: +1 Which is the letter `g` ;) Try `System.out.println((char) ('c' | 'd'));`

Comment: Try `'c' & 'd'` which matches `  or 'c' + 'd' which matches Ç and 'c'/'d' matches the nul byte \0 ;)

Comment: @PatrykDobrowolski Sorry didn't remember about bitwise...my (lame) excuse is that its not in the syllabus for SCJP6 ;)

Comment: *Non sequitur.* 1 == 2 is a Boolean expression but the operands aren't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`'c' | 'd'` wont return boolean. In this case `|` is bitwise OR not boolean OR.

You can see it in this example how it is calculated

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString('c'));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString('d'));
System.out.println("=======");
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString('c' | 'd'));
```

Output

```
1100011
1100100
=======
1100111
```

and binary 1100111 is equal to 103 decimal integer so it is *valid* case argument.

Answer (score 6):

`'c' | 'd'` is a bitwise or which results in `'g'`, so valid in the switch.

You can match more than one case without going to the if-statement like

```
switch(theChar) {
    case 'a':
        break;
    case 'b':
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
        System.out.println("c or d");
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
('c' | 'd')
```

is *bitwise or* so it won't return a *boolean* value, it is completely valid.

If you try that out like this:

```
System.out.println('c' | 'd');
```

it will print out 103 which is the ASCII code for **g**.

Comment: I believe you mean _g_, seeing as _C_ is 67 (103 in octal)

Answer (score 1):

If you do `'c' || 'd'` then you will get expected boolean error and won't compile.

`'c' | 'd'` is `bitwise OR`